# Is there a "service in area" algorithm based on US street addresses?

Tags: geolocation, gis, street-address

I have a database of US based street addresses for which a client of mine offers their services.  I am working on a form that would allow a customer to enter in their zip code or address to see if there is service in their area.

Is there a component or an algorithm "out there" somewhere that I can use as a template?

I have played with GIS and the tiger zips in a previous geolocation project but am not sure this is the best way to go.

Comment: In what form is the data stored? Address strings, zip code areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one crude approach:

1. First, the client's service
   territory needs to be geographically
   referenced as areal units or
   polygons on a map.
2. Second, get the geographic
   coordinates of the zip-code polygons
   (you can parse the shapefile).
3. Third, loop over and find the service
   polygons that overlap the chosen zip-code polygon
   by performing an [overlapping polygon
   test](http://www.fabianmoser.at/blog/2009/04/30/find-overlapping-polygons-with-python/). You can use the python
   [shapely library](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html).

Of course, you can speed things up by some how adding information on the centroid proximity structure or contiguity structure of the polygons so there was less looping needed.

good luck